# How to design browser independent html pages?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am trying to design a browser independent page using div. Sometimes the design view is different in different browsers??

Comment: This isn't really a question fit for SO, because it isn't necessarily about programming. Most browsers interpret html different than other browsers, that's why you can never design a browser independent design. The closest you can get is by using the Reset CSS By Eric Meyer.

Comment: yes. but trying to manage some elements little bit

Comment: You can resort to using IE conditional css hacks, `<!--[if IE]> <link href="ie_only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->`

http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Meyer's [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) will help smooth out some of the differences between different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a better alternative to the Meyer Reset IMO.

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Trying to make a site look the same in all browsers is pointless/impossible